# How can I use variable names other than $it$ in a StringTemplate partial?

Tags: stringtemplate

How can I use variable names other than $it$ in a StringTemplate partial?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's a partial?

anyway, if template has one arg the ST sets its value too

$a:t()$

for def

t(v) ::= "$v$"

is same as

t() ::= "$it$"

Comment: I'm a noob.  I guess there really aren't partials per se in StringTemplate?  Partial just means a template meant to be applied to an element of a collection.

Comment: oh, that's just mapping a template to an element or a vector of elements.  you can do that with a named template or an anonymous template block that acts like a lambda.

Answer (score 3):

**$it$**

Here is an example rendered using the default `$it$` variable name.

```
$["FOO","BAR"]:{<h1>$it$</h1>}$
```

**$x$**

In this example, the variable is named `$x$`

```
$["FOO","BAR"]:{x|<h1>$x$</h1>}$
```